# an example of direct product in Ab

Tags: category-theory

Can someone help me with this? Are there direct products in the category $Ab$ (the category of the abelian groups)? If yes, please, can you give me an example? Thank you?

Comment: Have you tried checking whether what one usually called the direct product of groups happen to work (hint: It does).

Comment: Is this correct? Let $G_{i}$ be a family of groups and we define $\pi G_{i}= \{(g_{i}): g_{i} in G_{i} \ }$ = P( by my notation). We have that $P$ is an abelian group and we define $p_{i}:P \to G_{i}$, by $p_{i}(g_{i})_{i \in I}=g_{i}$. I think that $P$ with the family $(p_{i})$ is a direct product in Ab.

Comment: @user308560 Correct. Though I'd prefer to write the elements as maps $I\to\bigcup_i G_i$. And if you let $S=\{\,f\in P\mid f(i)=0\text{ for all but finitely many }i\,\}$, together with $\iota_i:iG_i\to S$, $\iota_i(g_i)(j)=\begin{cases}g_i&i=j\\0&i\ne j\end{cases}$, you get a coproduct (aka. direct sum)

Comment: I dont know what happens, I cant correct that error in Latex..but it is ok you got my idea.

Comment: This example for direct sum is available both for the Ab category and for Gr category also?